# Save NotesDocument from .nsf to .eml file using c# or vb.net

Tags: vb.net, eml

I am reading a .nsf Lotus Notes file and am getting NotesDocument. I want to save this NotesDocument as a .eml file with all images, text, headers, and attachements. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you will not be able to retrieve the whole document as a Mime Message. Nevertheless, you could start with the "[NotesDocument.convertToMime](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CONVERTTOMIME_METHOD_JAVA.html?lang=de)"-method. Please forgive me, that my examples are in Java, C# and vb.net are not the languages of my choice ;)

So, let's begin with converting the document to a valid MIME-Message. The method grabs the RichTextItems and - as the name says - convert its content to MIME.

```
session.setConvertMIME(false);
doc.convertToMIME(Document.CVT_RT_TO_PLAINTEXT_AND_HTML);
```

Now you can get the MIME-representation of the Rich-Text with:

```
MIMEEntity mime = doc.getMIMEEntity("body");
Stream stream = session.createStream();
stream.open(File.createTempFile("entity",".eml").getAbsolutePath();
if (mime!=null){
 mime.getEntityAsText(stream);
}
```

For the other "normal" fields, you could add their value as a [X-Header](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CREATEHEADER_METHOD_MIMEENTITY_JAVA.html?lang=de) to the main MIME-Part. Just iterate through the items of the NotesDocument and add the fieldnames with a leading "X-" as headers of the MIME-message.

Again, I'm sorry that I can't help you with your languages. I hope you will find the right way.

For the concept of working with MIME in IBM Notes, have a look at [the IBM documentation.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_WORKING_WITH_A_MIME_ENTITY_STEPS_JAVA.html?lang=de)